# bpf_map_get_next_key and BPF_MAP_GET_NEXT_KEY returns -1 errno = 2 | ebpf xdp

Tags: c, linux, ebpf

So I have this kernel ebpf program and usersapce program, in userspace loader program I am calling `bpf_map_get_next_key` to get the key but calls to this returns -1

I checked the code in `bpf_map_get_next_key` there is not much except populating `union bpf_attr attr;` but followinfg sys_call inside the `bpf_map_get_next_key` cause errno to be `2` so I check googling and I just dont get any link useful except that it may be permission issue or somet thing [https://github.com/falcosecurity/falco/issues/1299]

So I like to knw what am I doing wrong in following user loader program and kernel ebpf program. Can any one please guide me through this error

this is libbpf function that cause syscall to return -1 libbpf/src/bpf.c

```
int bpf_map_get_next_key(int fd, const void *key, void *next_key)
{
    union bpf_attr attr;

    memset(&attr, 0, sizeof(attr));
    attr.map_fd = fd;
    attr.key = ptr_to_u64(key);
    attr.next_key = ptr_to_u64(next_key);

    int x=sys_bpf(BPF_MAP_GET_NEXT_KEY, &attr, sizeof(attr));
    printf("errno = %d | bpf_map_get_next_key = %d\n",errno,x);
    return x;
}
```

This is my kernel ebpf program

```
/* SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0 */

#include <linux/bpf.h>

#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/udp.h>
void *memcpy(void *, const void *, unsigned long);

int IPPROTO_UDP = 17;


struct share_me
{

    struct iphdr dest_ip;
};

    

struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps") ip_map = {
    .type = BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH,
    .key_size = sizeof(int),
    .value_size = sizeof(struct share_me),
    .max_entries = 64,  /* Assume netdev has no more than 64 queues */
};

struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps") xsks_map = {
    .type = BPF_MAP_TYPE_XSKMAP,
    .key_size = sizeof(int),
    .value_size = sizeof(int),
    .max_entries = 64,  /* Assume netdev has no more than 64 queues */
};



struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps") xdp_stats_map = {
    .type        = BPF_MAP_TYPE_PERCPU_ARRAY,
    .key_size    = sizeof(int),
    .value_size  = sizeof(__u32),
    .max_entries = 64,
};

SEC("xdp_sock")
int xdp_sock_prog(struct xdp_md *ctx)
{
    int index = ctx->rx_queue_index;
    __u32 *pkt_count;

    void *data = (void *)(long)ctx->data;
    void *data_end = (void *)(long)ctx->data_end;
    struct ethhdr *eth = data;
    struct share_me me;

    if ((void *)eth + sizeof(*eth) <= data_end)
    {

        struct iphdr *ip = data + sizeof(*eth);
        //me.dest_ip=ip;
        

        if(((void *)ip+sizeof(*ip))<=data_end)
        {   
             struct iphdr ip_temp=(struct iphdr)*ip;            
            memcpy(&me.dest_ip,&ip_temp,sizeof(ip_temp));
            bpf_map_lookup_elem(&ip_map, &index);
            bpf_map_update_elem(&ip_map,&index,&me,0);
            if ((void *)ip + sizeof(*ip) <= data_end)
            {

                if (ip->protocol == IPPROTO_UDP)
                {

           struct udphdr *udp = (void *)ip + sizeof(*ip);
           if ((void *)udp + sizeof(*udp) <= data_end)
           {
               //u64 value = htons(udp->dest);
               //counter.increment(value);
           }
                }
            }
         }  
    }



    pkt_count = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&xdp_stats_map, &index);
    if (pkt_count) {

        /* We pass every other packet */
        if ((*pkt_count)++ & 1)
            return XDP_DROP;
    }

    /* A set entry here means that the correspnding queue_id
     * has an active AF_XDP socket bound to it. */
    if (bpf_map_lookup_elem(&xsks_map, &index))
        return bpf_redirect_map(&xsks_map, index, 0);

    return XDP_PASS;
}

char _license[] SEC("license") = "GPL";
```

and this is my userspace loader program

```
/* SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0 */

#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/resource.h>

#include <bpf/bpf.h>
#include <bpf/xsk.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <linux/if_link.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <linux/ipv6.h>
#include <linux/icmpv6.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include "../common/common_params.h"
#include "../common/common_user_bpf_xdp.h"
#include "../common/common_libbpf.h"

struct share_me
{

    struct iphdr dest_ip;
};


int map_data(int map_fd)
{

    int key = 0, next_key=0;
    __u64 value;
    

    while (bpf_map_get_next_key(map_fd, &key, &next_key) == 0) 
    {
        struct share_me value;
        bpf_map_lookup_elem(map_fd, &next_key, &value);
        //print_stack(&next_key, value);
        struct iphdr *iph;
        iph=&value.dest_ip;
        printf("ihl = %x\n",iph->ihl);
        printf("tos = %x\n",iph->tos);
        printf("id = %x\n",ntohs(iph->id));         
        key = next_key;
    }   
    
}

int main()
{
    struct bpf_object *bpf_obj;
    struct bpf_program *bpf_prog;
    bpf_obj = load_bpf_object_file("af_xdp_kern.o", 0);
    if (!bpf_obj) {
        printf("ERR: loading file:\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAIL_BPF);
    }
    else{
        printf("load_bpf_object_file fine\n");
    }
             bpf_prog = bpf_program__next(NULL, bpf_obj);
    if (!bpf_prog)
    {
        printf("bpf_program_next:\n");
        exit(0);    
    }
    else{
        printf("bpf_progra_next fine\n");
    }
    int prog_fd = bpf_program__fd(bpf_prog);
    if (prog_fd <= 0) {
        printf("prog fd <0");
    }
    else{
        printf("bpf_program_fd fine\n");
    }
    int err = xdp_link_attach(if_nametoindex("eno1"), 0, prog_fd);
    if(err)
    {

        printf("xdp_link_attach\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
        printf("xdp_link_attacj fine\n");
    }   
    struct bpf_map *map1 = bpf_object__find_map_by_name(bpf_obj, "ip_map");
    int map_fd = bpf_map__fd(map1);
    if(map_fd<0)
    {
        printf("map fd <0\n");
        exit(0);

    }
    else
    {
        printf("bpf_map_fd fine\n");
    }
    
    map_data(map_fd);
    bpf_set_link_xdp_fd(if_nametoindex("eno1"), -1,0);
            
    return 0;

}
```

**Update**

bpf map dump ip_map

shows

```
# bpftool map dump ip_map 
Usage: /usr/lib/linux-tools/5.13.0-25-generic/bpftool map { show | list }   [MAP]
       /usr/lib/linux-tools/5.13.0-25-generic/bpftool map create     FILE type TYPE key KEY_SIZE value VALUE_SIZE \
                                  entries MAX_ENTRIES name NAME [flags FLAGS] \
                                  [inner_map MAP] [dev NAME]
       /usr/lib/linux-tools/5.13.0-25-generic/bpftool map dump       MAP
       /usr/lib/linux-tools/5.13.0-25-generic/bpftool map update     MAP [key DATA] [value VALUE] [UPDATE_FLAGS]
       /usr/lib/linux-tools/5.13.0-25-generic/bpftool map lookup     MAP [key DATA]
       /usr/lib/linux-tools/5.13.0-25-generic/bpftool map getnext    MAP [key DATA]
       /usr/lib/linux-tools/5.13.0-25-generic/bpftool map delete     MAP  key DATA
       /usr/lib/linux-tools/5.13.0-25-generic/bpftool map pin        MAP  FILE
       /usr/lib/linux-tools/5.13.0-25-generic/bpftool map event_pipe MAP [cpu N index M]
       /usr/lib/linux-tools/5.13.0-25-generic/bpftool map peek       MAP
       /usr/lib/linux-tools/5.13.0-25-generic/bpftool map push       MAP value VALUE
       /usr/lib/linux-tools/5.13.0-25-generic/bpftool map pop        MAP
       /usr/lib/linux-tools/5.13.0-25-generic/bpftool map enqueue    MAP value VALUE
       /usr/lib/linux-tools/5.13.0-25-generic/bpftool map dequeue    MAP
       /usr/lib/linux-tools/5.13.0-25-generic/bpftool map freeze     MAP
       /usr/lib/linux-tools/5.13.0-25-generic/bpftool map help

       MAP := { id MAP_ID | pinned FILE | name MAP_NAME }
       DATA := { [hex] BYTES }
       PROG := { id PROG_ID | pinned FILE | tag PROG_TAG | name PROG_NAME }
       VALUE := { DATA | MAP | PROG }
       UPDATE_FLAGS := { any | exist | noexist }
       TYPE := { hash | array | prog_array | perf_event_array | percpu_hash |
                 percpu_array | stack_trace | cgroup_array | lru_hash |
                 lru_percpu_hash | lpm_trie | array_of_maps | hash_of_maps |
                 devmap | devmap_hash | sockmap | cpumap | xskmap | sockhash |
                 cgroup_storage | reuseport_sockarray | percpu_cgroup_storage |
                 queue | stack | sk_storage | struct_ops | ringbuf | inode_storage |
          task_storage }
       OPTIONS := { {-j|--json} [{-p|--pretty}] | {-f|--bpffs} |
                {-m|--mapcompat} | {-n|--nomount} }
```

Comment: on Man pages it says `If key
              is the last element, -1 is returned and errno is set to
              ENOENT.  Other possible errno values are ENOMEM, EFAULT,
              EPERM, and EINVAL.  This method can be used to iterate
              over all elements in the map.` so I assume it the last element key that key=0 that I am feeding to attribute to syscall. So this means my map is not created or my kernel ebpf program and not updating ip_map with new values, so key stays at 0 which is last element. So what am I doing wrong in ebpf kernel program why my map key last element 0

Comment: ENOEN errno T means No such path or directory.. so why my map is not created, how to create map then to resolve the error

Comment: Yeah `ENOENT` sounds like no entry was found. Did you check that your map has any entries? `bpftool map dump <map>` should help you inspect it (you can also use it to validate that your map was created in the first place).

Comment: @Qeole please see the update to bpftool map dump command output, I am not sure how to make sense of the output. can u see and explain a little bit

Comment: This output is the usage function, to help you understand how to use it. You need to tell bpftool if you are passing the map identifier by id, name, or pinned file (`MAP := { id MAP_ID | pinned FILE | name MAP_NAME }`). In your case `ip_map` is its name, so try `bpftool map dump name ip_map`

Comment: Note that you are passing a pointer to an `int` for the value to `bpf_map_get_next_key()`, but your map has keys of type `struct iphdr`, which is bigger than an integer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241135/discussion-between-user786-and-qeole).

Comment: Found 0 elements

Comment: @Qeole what do u mean by this `Note that you are passing a pointer to an int for the value to bpf_map_get_next_key(), but your map has keys of type struct iphdr, which is bigger than an integer.` I have map defined as `struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps") ip_map = {
 .type = BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH,
 .key_size = sizeof(int),
 .value_size = sizeof(struct share_me),
 .max_entries = 64,  /* Assume netdev has no more than 64 queues */
};` do u mean `.value` is the sizeof key I thought share_me->iphdr is part of value. Can u please clarify

Comment: Uh my bad forget about that comment, I got confused. The pointers for getting the next key look all right, sorry.

Comment: I am running as root too

Comment: So if you have 0 elements in your map, it looks like your user space program is fine (`ENOENT` is expected in that case), and I would look at your eBPF program instead. Does it run as you expect? (Does it run at all? Does the interface get any packets? IP packets? Does the map update return an error code?) The `bpf_trace_printk()` helper may come handy to debug this sort of things. `bpftool prog profile` or enabling statistics (see `man bpftool-prog`) may help confirm your program runs.

Comment: @Qeole ok now my `bpftool map dump name` command showing my map and I can see `45 00 00 5b 9c 94 00 00  76 06 99 34 8e fa b5 22
c0 a8 0a 0f` printed in output of `bpftool map dump name` command so its IP header starts with `iph->ihl + version=45 and so on` my my function `bpf_map_get_next_key` still returning -1. Now do u know how to debug for this. #bpftool map dump name ip_map: `key:
00 00 00 00
value:
45 00 00 5b 9c 94 00 00  76 06 99 34 8e fa b5 22
c0 a8 0a 0f
Found 1 element`

Comment: @Qeole ok so what i found is map's element with key=0 does not exists. SO I like to know is there any helper function in libbpf  to get the last key of a map in userspace loader program

Comment: If there are elements in your map but key `0` doesn't exist, `bpf_map_get_next_key(fd, NULL, &next_key)` should set `next_key` to the first available key, and you should be able to iterate from there. See [the doc for `BPF_MAP_GET_NEXT_KEY`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16/source/include/uapi/linux/bpf.h#L179).